# SQL 2008 R2 Merge Replication - Clearing Skipped Schema Changes

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, merge-replication

A developer made a change to our production database that is using merge replication to a table (Activity).  That table has a Foreign constraint that points to a table that is not part of replication and does not exist at the replicated database. This broke replication.  To get replication up and running, I used the sp_markpendingschemachange procedure to skip the schema changes.  This worked, but now I am left with the records still in the sysmergeschemaarticles table, just marked skipped.  At this point, I want to get rid of the records so they get executed in the future.

My solution is to perform a snapshot (at a less busy time) assuming that the this will clear the sysmergeschemaarticles table of any ddl changes but have not found any supporting documentation to support this.  Anyone have an experience with this type of situation that can support this solution or propose a new better one?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Luckily the Network Admin found some space for a couple of VM to test the solution. I tested the solution and it worked perfectly.